# Не могу записать загружаемый CD

Tags: c, ассемблер, boot, cd

Скомпилировал ядро, но оно не грузится с диска CD-R и не грузится в VirtualBox, но всё работает в qemu, мне надо чтобы грузилось с моего CD-R, если кто-то знает помогите пожалуйста выкладываю все свои исходники:

первый файл:

```
;;kernel.asm

;nasm directive - 32 bit
bits 32 ;директива nasm - 32 bit
section .text
    ;multiboot spec
    align 4
    dd 0x1BADB002       ;магические числа
    dd 0x00                    ;флаги 
    dd - (0x1BADB002 + 0x00) ;контрольная сумма. мч+ф+кс должнло равняться нулю

global start
extern kmain    ;kmain определена в C-файле


start:
   cli ;блокировка прерываний
   mov esp, stack_space ;установка указателя стека
   call kmain
   hlt ;остановка процессора


section .bss
resb 8192 ;8KB на стёк
stack_space:
```

второй файл:

```
/*
* kernel.c
*/
void kmain(void)
{
    const char *str = "my first kernel";
    char *vidptr = (char*)0xb8000;      //видео память начинается здесь
    unsigned int i = 0;
    unsigned int j = 0;

    /* этот цикл очищает экран */
    while(j < 80 * 25 * 2){
    /* пустой символ */
        vidptr[j] = ' ';
    /* байт атрибутов */
        vidptr[j+1] = 0x17;
        j = j + 2;
    }

    j = 0;

    /* в этом цикле строка записывается в видео память */
    while(str[j] != '\0'){
    /* ascii отображение */
        vidptr[i] = str[j];
        vidptr[i+1] = 0x17;
        ++j;
        i = i + 2;
    }
    return;
}
```

третий файл:

```
/*
* link.ld
*/
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf32-i386)
ENTRY(start)
SECTIONS
  {
    . = 0x100000;
    .text    : { *(.text)  }
    .data   :  { *(.data)  }
    .bss     : { *(.bss)   }
  }
```

Заранее спасибо за ответ, работаю на Ubuntu 16.04 x86_64

Answer (score 0):

Это ядро загружается с помощью `GRUB`. Чтобы загрузить его в `VirtualBox` или с `CD-R` необходимо написать свой загрузчик с переходом в защищённый режим и передать управление на ядро. Простой пример можно найти [здесь](https://github.com/cfenollosa/os-tutorial).